# Dealing with a gfortran error?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I usually do some pieces of code in Fortran and C for my job, but since some days ago I get the following error:

$ gfortran D.f -o D.x
gfortran: error trying to exec 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory

(I have Ubuntu 14.04 on a I7, 8cores and 64b)

I did try searching on the forums and several option but nothing seems to work ... Could somebody help ... ?

I guess the problem started when I did something to install adobereader and/or skype.

---

Sorry and OK. locate f951 gives:

```
$ locate f951
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/f951
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/powerpc-linux-gnu/4.8/f951
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/4.8/f951
$
```

And the end of the command touch D.f && strace gfortran -c D.f > PATH-TO-F951.txt gives:

```
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.0.2/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.0.2/x86_64-linux-gnu/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.0.2/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
vfork(gfortran: error trying to exec 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory
)                                 = 8373
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=8373, si_status=255, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
 wait4(8373, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 255}], 0, NULL) = 8373
 stat("/tmp/ccf8JxJd.s", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
 unlink("/tmp/ccf8JxJd.s")               = 0
 exit_group(1)                           = ?
 +++ exited with 1 +++
 $
```

Well I can see that there is something wrong, I believe ..., with "suse-linux" ? but how to correct it?

Comment: Thank you. I did try it already and many others but could not solve the problem ...

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit Linux?  What do you get when you type *gfortran --version*?

Comment: Looks like https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48697 but why it should happen after installing adobe/skype doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: What is the something you did to install them?

Comment: Thanks for these comments. Indeed it is weird but unfortunately I can not say after installing what it stop working ...

Answer (score 1):

According to the file list for the `gfortran` package in Ubuntu 14.04, `f951` can be found here: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951`. You can check first for existence/permissions:

```
ls -lF /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951
file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951
```

If the executable is there, then probably it can't be found for some reason.

According to some random internet source, it might be that Adobe Acrobat is corrupting `/usr/lib/gcc/...`, placing its own libraries there, but I can't deny/confirm this as I neither have Ubuntu nor Adobe Acrobat.

I would think the easiest option is to reinstall gcc and gfortran?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc gfortran
```

Comment: Thanks for this help. The f951 executable is there, exactly! And I think you are write with Adobe. I did try your suggestion of the updating and re-installing but still does not work.

Comment: OK, if the file is there, what does `touch dummy.f && strace gfortran -c dummy.f` give you? It should tell you where it is looking for `f951`.

Comment: Ok. Do I paste here what I've got for such a comand? <br/> First let me show you the places where 'f951' is: <br/> $ locate f951 <br/>
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951 <br/> 
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951 <br/>
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/f951 <br/>
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/powerpc-linux-gnu/4.8/f951 <br/>
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/4.8/f951 <br/>
$ <br/>

Comment: Then running the above comand I've got (almost at the end):  <br/>  close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.0.2/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.0.2/x86_64-linux-gnu/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.0.2/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/f951", 0x7fff0490e630) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
vfork(gfortran: error trying to exec 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory
)                                 = 8373
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=8373, si_status=255, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(8373, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 255}], 0, NULL) = 8373
stat("/tmp/ccf8JxJd.s", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0

Comment: unlink("/tmp/ccf8JxJd.s")               = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
$

Comment: pasting that in a comment was not such a good idea, you should edit your question and put it there formatted as `code` :) Small reminder in case you missed that: `locate` keeps a database, you should make sure you updated it to get reliable results. It seems gfortran doesn't look for f951 where it is supposed to be (might be clearer if you put it in the question). Is `/usr/lib64` a link to `/usr/lib` ?

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't search the regular places too, but you could of course try setting `export GCC_EXEC_PREFIX=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/` and see if that at least points it to the correct place.

Comment: Excellent! Very happy for this help! Perhaps as you said before. Adobe corrupts some of the scripts which contain the variable GCC_EXEC_PREFIX and no reinstallation fix it at all ... Very bad !!!  Which one is the Script which contain this variable ???

Comment: I don't know, normally you should not need to set `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` to make it work. And even if this variable was set incorrectly, it should still search in the proper place. Also, as I don't know what you exactly did to your setup to brake it, it's hard to speculate what went wrong. I can only recommend a complete reinstallation + never install custom software in standard system locations with root permissions unless you know what you are doing is safe.

Comment: Sure, I agree but it is the first time I get into this. I'm using Ubunte sine it was in the version ~7 or something like (maby earlier) that and always installed compilers, adobe, etc without any problem ...